# "self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES" not working with UITabBarController

Tags: xcode, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, back-button

I have a UINavigationController with a UITabBarController nested within it. I'm trying to hide the back button in the navigation bar so that I could replace it with a custom button. But I can't seem to do this once one of the tabs is the active view.

I've tried

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:NO];
```

but to no avail.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drag and drop, than you can just drop a navigation bar, place a button over it and add selectors for it. Only if you put a bar button item over it you will have problem of hide and all. But then again why do you want to use a navigation bar if you are not using it's inbuilt properties.

Another solution would be to create a custom bar or a image view and load with your own image or colour of the bar. Just create a bar similar to a navigation bar, uiimageview - setimage - some image like nav bar. And than place buttons - custom buttons as per your requirement.